# One user cannot edit data in Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I have an inventory tracking Access database where a user should be able to open the "Edit Inventory" table, and edit the on-hand values of items in our department.  However, the computer that uses this the most is now displaying a message of "This dataset is not updatable."  I tried to edit the data from my computer as well as another user, both of which worked just fine. I checked to make sure the mapping of this computer was correct, and it is.

I am by far no expert on Access.  This database pre-dates me and the creator has since retired.
That being said, I am wondering if it has to do with how this computer is logged into. Because it is a shared computer, it has very limited access to tools--it is basically only used for this inventory file.  Because of the shared status, every time I open access, it asks the user to log into Microsoft, which we then skip because there is no shared Microsoft account. We log into this computer using "computername[departmentname]."  I checked the client settings to ensure everything was shared and no locking was occurring. This just began occurring 2 days ago, so it is a very new issue that came up out of the blue.

Any advice or ideas is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check that the user has write permissions on the database file (frontend + backend if split).

Comment: Yes. As Andre said, the problem is probably permissions. I suppose the shared database is in some network drive. Try making a copy of the database to a different folder to isolate the problem. If you are still stump, please give more details, like how is the directories setup, if the database is divided in data and programs or not, what happen if you try to create a new file from the problem computer into the folder with the access database, what happens if you copy the programs and data to a local disk in the problem computer and run it, that kind o things.